# MySQL: Select multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want to select multiple tables with MySQL.
But I don't know exactly the name of them, but they have all the same structure.

For example:

```
table_345:
id || row_1 || row_2 || row_3
```

I want to have something like that:

```
SELECT `id` FROM table_*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP with your MySQL database you can use [mysql_list_tables()](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php) to get the list of tables in your database. That list can then be filtered easily using [strpos()](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Once you have your list of tables, you can use [SQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) to combine the result sets from your tables.

I hope there's a really good reason for you to choose this kind of design since it could get really ugly, really fast.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `information_schema.TABLES` (table names are case sensitive in MySQL) to retrieve the list of tables.  You can then construct a dynamic query and run it with `EXECUTE STMT`. Here's an example:

```
SET @query = '';

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT @query := CONCAT(@query,if(@query = '','',' union all '),
        'select * from ', T.`TABLE_NAME`)
    FROM information_schema.TABLES T 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabaseName'
) sub
WHERE 1=0;

PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

P.S. Multi-line statements like this don't work in the query browser, but they do in the command line.  Save the commands in a file called `sqlcommands.txt` and you can run them like:

```
mysql -u user -p password dbname < sqlcommands.txt
```